# sending data properly through the MVC chain in code igniter

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

As I am new to code igniter and MVC, I am slowly but surely getting my login form to log a user in via data I've stored in the db.

I have pieced together my current version from articles and advice from forums, however I am a little confused at this point as to why it seems that data is not being stored and sent properly.

I have my login form set up to re-load the form if the password is incorrect ( eventually will add a message)

That being said, when I put in the proper login info it reloads the page. That can only tell me that I am not communicating with the db properly or not sending and or storing info with my `$data` variable properly.

Here is what I have code wise:

Model:

```
<?php

class User_model extends CI_Model {
   function __construct()
        {
            // Call the Model constructor
            parent::__construct();
        }

    function login($data = array())
    {
    // validate data
    if( !empty($data) ) return FALSE;

    // retrieve query
    $query = $this->db
            ->from('users')
            ->where($data)
            ->get();

    // Check if query row exists
    if($query->row())
    {
        // Query row exists, return query row
        return $query->row();
    }
    else
    {
        // Query row doesn't exist, return FALSE
        return FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

View:

```
title>Login</title>

<!--MAKE SURE SIGNED OUT HEADER IS IMPLEMENTED FOR ALL SIGNED OUT PAGES INCLUDING THIS ONE-->

<div class="structure clearfix">
    <h1 class="title_header">
        Sign In
    </h1>
    <div id="signin_form">
        <?php
        echo validation_errors(); 
        echo form_open('auth/validate_credentials');
        echo "<div class='form_text_signin'>";
        echo "Email";
        echo "</div>";
        echo form_input('email');
        echo "<div class='form_text_signin'>";
        echo "Password";
        echo "</div>";
        echo form_input('password');
        echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');
        echo form_close();
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
<?php
class Auth extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct()
        {
            // Call the Model constructor
            parent::__construct();
        }

    // this is automatically called if no other function is called
    // it simply turns around and calls the login() function to show the login page

    public function index() {

        $this->login();
    }

    public function login() {   
    $data['main_content'] = 'auth/login';
    $this->load->view('includes/templates/main_page_template', $data);

    }

    function validate_credentials () {
        $query = $this->load->model('user_model');



        if($query)
        {
            $data = array(
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('account/dashboard');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->index();
        }
    }
}
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're calling the login method from your user_model class at any point - you're just instantiating the class.  You should be calling the model method from your controller - I haven't tested this code but hopefully it gets you on the right track:

```
    function validate_credentials () {
        $this->load->model('User_model');
        $data = array(
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password')
        );
        $query = $this->User_model->login($data);

        if($query)
        {
            $data['is_logged_in'] = true;
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('account/dashboard');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->index();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've adopted your code and still loading the login form. I am unsure if function login($data = array()) in the model is collecting the data created in controller $this->load->model('user_model');
          $data = array(
              'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
              'password' => $this->input->post('password')
          );
          $query = $this->user_model->login($data);

Comment: I'm assuming this is ok as is login($data = array()), or needs to have the array in it

Comment: You might want to try putting "$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);" somewhere in your controller and see if the query is running at all.  If not you know the script isn't getting that far and perhaps the data isn't being correctly passed to the login method of your model.

Comment: good call. Under 'Queries' is displays 'database driver is not currently loaded'